# UITabbarItem seems to ignore Swedish characters

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a simple view controller subclassed from`UITabBarController`. On assigning the items to the tab bar controller i am facing some issues with the titles of the `UITabBarItem`

```
class LandingVC: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Ssettings", bundle: nil)
    let vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bookID")
    let tab1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Föo", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
    vc1.tabBarItem = tab1

    let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsID")
    let tab2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Sök", image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
    vc2.tabBarItem = tab2

    self.viewControllers = [vc1, vc2]
    }
}
```

But strangely the tabbar controller displays items with title `Sok` and `Foo` ignoring the swedish characters. Even a tab bar systemItem seems to fail, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have tried your code and it's working fine. Check the result here https://i.gyazo.com/4bf1ddcc081a21d10cc840a29939d44f.png

Comment: Is there any chance you are using a special font that has trouble with those characters?

Comment: @rmaddy You are a hero! Never thought about that